# Several tors services in one docker container

Tags: docker, tor

I have `dockerfile` with run tor in docker:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add tor curl && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    cp /etc/tor/torrc.sample /etc/tor/torrc && \
    echo "SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9050" > /etc/tor/torrc
EXPOSE 9050
USER tor
CMD /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc
```

It works. I want to run several tors in one dockerfile and open different ports (9051,9052, etc). I can create `docker-compose.yml` in which for every port create one docker, but it isn't a good solution in my opinion.

May be anybody know how run several tors and publish theirs ports from docker?

Comment: I would recommend you to use this shell script in this case https://github.com/jseidl/Multi-TOR

Comment: One service per one container is a rule that will serve you well in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @TarunLalwani thank you, i'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me help this dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add tor curl bash && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    cp /etc/tor/torrc.sample /etc/tor/torrc

EXPOSE 9050-9060

ADD start.sh /usr/local/bin/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start.sh

RUN echo | sed -i 's/\r$//' /usr/local/bin/start.sh

CMD /usr/local/bin/start.sh
```

And script start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#making script to stop on 1st error
set -e

# Original script from
# http://blog.databigbang.com/distributed-scraping-with-multiple-tor-circuits/

# if defined TOR_INSTANCE env variable sets the number of tor instances (default 10)
TOR_INSTANCES=${TOR_INSTANCES:=10 }

# if defined TOR_OPTIONSE env variable can be used to add options to TOR
TOR_OPTIONS=${TOR_OPTIONS:=''}

base_socks_port=9050
base_control_port=11000
dir_data="/tmp/multitor.$$"

# Create data directory if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d $dir_data ]; then
        mkdir $dir_data
fi


if [ ! $TOR_INSTANCES ] || [ $TOR_INSTANCES -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Please supply an instance count"
    exit 1
fi

for i in $(seq $TOR_INSTANCES)
do
        j=$((i+1))

        socks_port=$((base_socks_port+i))
        control_port=$((base_control_port+i))

        if [ ! -d "$dir_data/tor$i" ]; then
                echo "Creating directory $dir_data/tor$i"
                mkdir "$dir_data/tor$i" && chmod -R 700 "$dir_data/tor$i"
        fi

        # Take into account that authentication for the control port is disabled. Must be used in secure and controlled environments
        echo "Running: tor --RunAsDaemon 1 --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword \"\" --ControlPort 0.0.0.0:$control_port --PidFile tor$i.pid --SocksPort 0.0.0.0:$socks_port --DataDirectory $dir_data/tor$i  -f /etc/tor/torrc"

        tor --RunAsDaemon 1 --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword "" --PidFile $dir_data/tor$i/tor$i.pid --SocksPort 0.0.0.0:$socks_port --DataDirectory $dir_data/tor$i
done

# So that the container doesn't shut down, sleep this thread
sleep infinity
```

Build and start:

`docker build -t torone ./`

`docker run -d -e "TOR_INSTANCES=10" -p 9050-9060:9050-9060 --rm --name torone torone`

TOR_INSTANCES - contains how many tors processes want to start.